# How can I use a text and a function php

Tags: php

I want to display a text and a function in same sentence:

```
<?php echo 'Right sidebar'; ?>
<?php echo the_content(); ?>
```

Something like this:

```
<?php echo 'Right sidebar' the_content(); ?>
```

But it didin't, it's possible to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php echo "Right sidebar".get_the_content(); ?>
```

Don't use echo for [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/), it's already echoed out, use [`get_the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) instead.